How can I include Send Time in a Marketing Cloud email intelligence report?
I'm building a SFMC intelligence report that includes dozens of emails sent on the same day. I'd like to include send time in the report to easily differentiate each email, but I'm not seeing a Send Time option in the Measurement or Dimension fields. Does anyone have a solution?
